# Django multitenant migration raises KeyError: "prune"

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant

So I've been working in a project for a while, and haven't really changed the models at all, and therefore haven't done any migrations. Now I needed to add two new fields and delete another one, which should be normally fine. I'm using `django-tenants`, so my command to run the migrations is `./manage.py migrate_schemas`.
Now, whenever I run that,  I get the error `KeyError: "prune"` (the full traceback is below) in what seems to be internal code of Django.

Now, afterwards I tried reverting my changes, so no new migration and running the comnad again, and got the same error. I also thought that maybe the database had gotten "dirty" at some point, so I tried migrating a clean database from scratch, with the same result. The migrations don't even get to start.

Has anyone ever encountered something similar?

The full traceback (I have simplified the paths)

```
[standard:public] === Starting migration
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ":directory/./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File ":directory/./manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "$venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "$/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "$venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "$venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "$venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_tenants/management/commands/migrate_schemas.py", line 52, in handle
    executor.run_migrations(tenants=[self.PUBLIC_SCHEMA_NAME])
  File "$venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_tenants/migration_executors/standard.py", line 11, in run_migrations
    run_migrations(self.args, self.options, self.codename, self.PUBLIC_SCHEMA_NAME)
  File "$venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_tenants/migration_executors/base.py", line 53, in run_migrations
    MigrateCommand(stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr).execute(*args, **options)
  File "$venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "$venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "$venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 188, in handle
    if options["prune"]:
KeyError: 'prune'
```

Comment: The prune option is new in Django 4.1, your version of `django-tenents` doesn't appear to be compatible - either updated `django-tenents`  to the latest or downgrade Django to one that's supported (4.0 probably)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like version incompatibility.

`prune` option [added to Django](https://github.com/django/django/commit/2d8232fa716f5fe46eec9f35a0e90c2d0f126279) couple months ago (`Jan 22, 2022`)

If you want to use newer Django you have to patch `django-tenants` manually and [add `--prune` argument](https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants/blob/fc4956067fb3a486ae04472374705298f3a474f6/django_tenants/management/commands/migrate_schemas.py#L10)

```py
def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument(
        '--prune', action='store_true', dest='prune',
        help='Delete nonexistent migrations from the django_migrations table.',
    )
```

<sub>PS I couldn't find [issue](https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants/issues?q=prune) related to `prune`, so you may create new one ;)</sub>

Comment: That does seem to be the issue. I searched everywhere for a reference to this error, but couldn't find anything. The closest was a similar issue when the option `--plan` was added in Django 2.2. I will just make sure tomorrow that this is the issue and then accept the answer!

Comment: Downgrading to 4.0.5 did the trick, and I've already created the issue and related pull request in `django-tenants`. Thank you very much for your help, @rzlvmp!